# Join 3+ tables using Doctrine Query Builder or MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, where-clause

I am new to symfony2 development. I am trying to develop eschool course management system and here is my summary of 6 tables.

```
    Students
    ----------
    Id  Firstname
    1   John
    2   Susan
    3   Sarah

    Courses
    ----------
    Id  Name
    1   ICT
    2   Math
    3   PE

    Students_Courses
    ----------
    Student_Id  Course_Id
       1          1
       1          3
       2          2
       2          1
       3          1

    Grades
    ----------
    Id Student_Id Course_Id Grade Quarter_Id
    1      1          1        90      1
    2      2          1        80      1

    Quarters
    -----------
    Id Name
    1  Semester 1
    2  Semester 2
    3  Semester 3
    4  Semester 4

    Quarters_Courses
    ------------
    Quarter_id     Course_Id
        1             1
        3             1
        2             2
        4             3
```

I am using query below

```
    SELECT * FROM Students AS s LEFT JOIN Grades as g on g.student_id = s.id where g.quarter_id=1
```

And it shows me result below

```
    John      90
    Susan     80
```

But I want query which shows result below (if quarter_id is equal to 1)

```
    John      90
    Susan     80
    Sarah
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your condition in **JOIN** instead of **WHERE** condition because if you put any condition of right table in where condition then it will treat as **INNER JOIN** instead of **LEFT JOIN:**

Try this:

```
SELECT s.Firstname, IFNULL(g.Grade, '') AS Grade  
FROM Students AS s 
LEFT JOIN Grades as g on g.student_id = s.id AND g.quarter_id=1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and it seems to work. But Additionally how can I filter by course?

Comment: When I use "SELECT * 
FROM Students AS s 
LEFT JOIN Grades as g on g.student_id = s.id AND g.quarter_id=1 AND g.course_id = 1" It shows all students who are in course which is related to quarter 1. Not only students who are in course 1 and quarter 1.

Comment: Every course can be conducted in different semesters. For example: ICT course could be conducted Semester 1 and Semester 2 only not in Semester 3 and Semester 4. Semesester 1 and Semester 2 can have grades for each of students. Also it could be changable this is why I have to filter by course too.

Comment: For example: School has Math and ICT courses. Math course is conducted in Semester 2 and Semester 3 and it has 2 students. ICT course is conducted in Semester 1 only and it has 3 students. But 2 students of them have grades and the other one has not grade(no related record in Grade table.). As a query result it must show me 2 students with grades and one student's only name.

Comment: If I add course_id=1 it shows me all three students in Student table. But only 2 of them is selected ICT course currently (course_id=1)